# Обход функционала игры путем исправления значений в консоли разработчика JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Можно ли как-то устранить уязвимость в игре-кликере, которую я делаю. Суть уязвимости: при нажатии на картинку, на экране прибавляется определенное кол-во поинтов (в моем случае - это один поинт). Но, если открыть инструменты разработчика и исправить в файле main.js цифру **1** на цифру **100**, то прибавится уже **сотня** поинтов. Таким образом игрок может получить за один клик **неограниченное** количество очков. Ванильный JavaScript.
Код обработчика событий:

```
const clicker = document.querySelector('.clicker');

clicker.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  value += 1 //на этом моменте можно поставить любое число
  valute.innerHTML = value.toString();
});
```

Comment: что с этими очками потом происходит? Хранятся на сервере? Есть авторизация? Какая то таблица результатов игроков? Если ничего нет, то пусть сам себя обманывает)

Comment: При клике отправляется зщапрос на сервер и там прибавляются очки по тому количеству, что вы настроете ТАМ